# MSGraph Authenticating to dynamics with correct token gives 401

Tags: authentication, microsoft-dynamics, microsoft-graph-api

Using the following code I can connect to MSGraph (different resource url) and fetch the data that I need, but I'm struggling to realise how to do the same for Microsoft Dynamics (CRM)

```
public static async Task<string> GetTokenForApplication(string resourceUrl)
{
    AuthenticationContext authenticationContext = 
         new AuthenticationContext(AppModeConstants.AuthString, false);

    ClientCredential clientCred = new ClientCredential(AppModeConstants.ClientId, AppModeConstants.ClientSecret);
    AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = await authenticationContext
           AcquireTokenAsync("resourceUrl", clientCred);

    TokenForApplication = authenticationResult.AccessToken;
}

public static async Task CrmTest()
{
        var token = await AuthenticationHelper.GetTokenForApplication(@"https://myapp.crm4.dynamics.com/");

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        var response = await client.GetAsync(@"https://myapp.crm4.dynamics.com/api/data/v8.2/accounts");
}
```

Although I fetch the right token I'll still get a 401: Unauthorized:

```
{StatusCode: 401, ReasonPhrase: 'Unauthorized', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  REQ_ID: 790b38b0-c8c0-4878-a318-e490ee7db57a
  Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
  Date: Thu, 11 May 2017 15:33:41 GMT
  Set-Cookie: crmf5cookie=!UXdAbawdawdal8sNiJ9xy74dAiawdawdDnDsomethingAolDYjkR7innjWIYQ1pV+DcZ9A=;secure; path=/
  Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
  WWW-Authenticate: Bearer authorization_uri=https://login.windows.net/b8faag21-awda-awda-90s4-f8652ss86ddb/oauth2/authorize, resource_id=https://myapp.crm4.dynamics.com/
  X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
  Content-Length: 49
  Content-Type: text/html
}}
```

A 403 I would understand, but a 401 means that I'm simply using the wrong authentication. Any input on this would be appreciated.

**Edit: Is it even possible to access CRM data as an application? There are only delegated permissions available in the azure portal, no application permissions.**

Answer (score 0):

While both Dynamics CRM and Graph leverage Azure AD accounts, they have different permission scopes and prerequisites.

To get started, you'll want to follow this [Walkthrough: Register a Dynamics 365 app with Azure Active Directory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt622431.aspx).

Comment: Could you expand on that? I've given the application the right permissions (Dynamics CRM online through Azure portal/Active directory). Edit: The walkthrough also references the old portal which I can not access (eventhough I have the right admin permissions), weird.